# How can I alternate ID's using selenium in python?

Tags: python, selenium, outlook, automation

I'm trying to automate the email creation process on Outlook using Selenium in Python and certain input ID's alternate like the one for the first name alternates between "TextField64" and"TextField65". I can't seem to get how to have my code check for "TextField64" and if that is not there check for "TextField65"

I have tried to use find_element_by_css_name, find_element_by_css_selector, but they all alternate and I find it easier to use find_element_by_id.

```
if len (driver.find_element_by_id('TextField64'))==0:
    First = driver.find_element_by_id('TextField65')

elif len (driver.find_element_by_id('TextField65'))==0:
    First = driver.find_element_by_id('TextField64')
```

I get this when it runs the first line without checking the else line.
"line 81, in 
    if len (driver.find_element_by_id('TextField64'))==0:"

It should be checking the else line and setting "First" variable accordingly.

Comment: welcome to SO!! please read [mcve] and provide the reproducible example

Answer (score 0):

`WebElement` has no `len()` .

To check the length count 0 you need to use `driver.find_elements_by_id()`

Try the below code.

```
if len(driver.find_elements_by_id('TextField64'))==0:
    First = driver.find_element_by_id('TextField65')

elif len(driver.find_elements_by_id('TextField65'))==0:
    First = driver.find_element_by_id('TextField64')
```

Comment: Correct. `find_elements_by_id()` returns a list of `WebElement`s. And you can check whether this list is empty or not to determine which ID to use.

Comment: To make the code a little bit cleaner at the cost of clarity, the checks for 0 (i.e. `== 0`) can be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a CSS selector and the OR operator.

```
First = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("TextField64,TextField65")
```

Comment: No feedback from the downvoter? How am I supposed to improve this and other answers if you don't leave any comment indicating what I should fix?